# Ошибка в React.js - TypeError: createSort is not a function

Tags: javascript, type-error, reactjs

Уважаемые разработчики. Я новичок в React.js и поэтому некоторые ошибки для меня очень не понятны.
У меня есть массив объектов созданный с помощью хука useState. Этот массив это "посты людей", которые я хочу сортировать по названию или содержанию(первой букве). Сортировка происходит в зависимости от значения select.
Функция createSort(callback) не функция, я не понимаю почему.
Не буду долго всё описывать, думаю вы поймёте мой простой код)
Любая помощь будет очень полезна:)

Файл TwoPostSort.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const TwoPostSort = ({ options, defaultSort}, {createSort}) => {

    const [ValueSort, setValueSort] = useState('');
    
    const SortNeW = () => {
        const NewSort = [ValueSort].reduce(function(a, b){
            return a + b;
        });
    
        createSort(NewSort);
    
        console.log(NewSort);
    }

    return (
        <div style={{ margin: '5px 0px 30px 0px' }}>
            <select 
            value={ValueSort}
            onChange={e => setValueSort(e.target.value)}
            onChange={SortNeW}
            >
                <option disabled value="">{defaultSort}</option>
                {options.map(option =>
                    <option key={option.toString()} value={option.value}>
                        {option.name}
                    </option>
                )}
            </select>
        </div>
    );

};

export default TwoPostSort;
```

Файл App.js

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import TwoPostSort from "./components/TwoPostSort";

function App() {
  const [postu, setPostu] = useState([
    { id: 10, title: "Aa", body: "12" },
    { id: 11, title: "aA", body: "13" },
    { id: 12, title: "bb", body: "11" },
  ]);

  const [selectorSort, setselectorSort] = useState("");

  const CreateNewSort = (NewSort) => {
    setselectorSort(NewSort);
    console.log(NewSort);
    setPostu([...postu].sort((a, b) => a[NewSort].localeCompare(b[NewSort])));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <TwoPostSort
        value={selectorSort}
        createSort={CreateNewSort}
        defaultSort="Сортировка"
        options={[
          { value: "title", name: "По названию" },
          { value: "body", name: "По описанию" },
        ]}
      />

      
      {postu.length !== 0 ? (
        <PostList postuu={postu}/>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "green" }}>
            Посты не найдены
          </h1>
        </div>
      )}

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Файл PostList.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import MyButton from './Form/MyButton';


const PostList = ({ postuu, remove }) => {

    return (
        <ul>
            {postuu.map(post => <PostItem id={post.id} title={post.title} body={post.body} key={post.toString()} remove={remove} post={post} />)}
        </ul>
    );
}


const PostItem = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className="post">
            <div className="post__content">
                <strong>{props.id}</strong><br />
                <span>{props.title}{props.body}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="post__btn">
                <MyButton
                    onClick={() => props.remove(props.post)}>
                    Удалить
                </MyButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PostList;
```

Comment: У вас опечатка в ```const TwoPostSort = ({ options, defaultSort}, {createSort}) => {```,
 поменяйте на ```const TwoPostSort = ({ options, defaultSort, createSort}) => {```

Comment: Да, я знаю. Это я просто гулялся, пробовал разные варианты. Это никак не меняет ситуацию. Раньше было по другому